# Add ISBLANK validation before comparing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Actually I am not much familiar with Excel formulas. 
I am using dates from Column E and F to color cells

```
 =+IF(AND(DATEVALUE(I1)>=DATEVALUE($E$2);DATEVALUE(I1)<=DATEVALUE($F$2));1;2)
```

This formula is working fine when there is value present for column E and F.
if there is no value present for E and F it results error value.

I know little bit about `ISBLANK()` function.

I want to add condition to check cell E2 and F2 are not blank before my existing formula. Can you please suggest the proper syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your suggestions and valuable time.

But after reading some office.com documentation I find a proper solution. 
`IFERROR` is more suitable than `ISBLANK` for my problem

instead of checking for blank cells I directly apply `DATEVALUE()` on cell . so if there is a blank cell `DATEVALUE()` return error and `IFERROR()` condition set value 2.

```
=+IF(AND(DATEVALUE(G1)>=IFERROR(DATEVALUE($E$7),0),DATEVALUE(G1)<=IFERROR(DATEVALUE($F$7),0)),1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your current operations in a function that checks each cell. If either of them is blank, you probably want to return "", or else the IF will automatically return FALSE.

You could use a chain of ifs, but since ISBLANK returns a boolean we can instead use an OR.

```
OR(ISBLANK($E$2),ISBLANK($F$2))
```

will return TRUE if either of the two cells is blank, so you'll need to put your operations into the False option, giving us:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK($E$2),ISBLANK($F$2)),"",IF(AND(DATEVALUE(I1)>=DATEVALUE($E$2),DATEVALUE(I1)<=DATEVALUE($F$2)),1,2))
```

Although you seem to have strange syntax, probably down to language settings or something, so you may prefer this:

```
=+IF(OR(ISBLANK($E$2),ISBLANK($F$2));"";IF(AND(DATEVALUE(I1)>=DATEVALUE($E$2);DATEVALUE(I1)<=DATEVALUE($F$2));1;2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition which will ensure that both are not blank:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK($E$2),ISBLANK*($F$2), your operations, "")
```